# Expressing that a functor is natural

Tags: category-theory

The Haskell `List: Type -> Type` constructor implements the `Functor` typeclass with function `fmap f = map f`. This functor that applies the morphism `f` to each element of a list works, but there are other equally valid functors, for example `fmap f = map f . rev` which first reverses the list before mapping over it. Is there a concept in category theory that expresses the fact that the first choice of functor is in some sense "more natural" for this type constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a functor requires two properties:

1. `fmap id = id`
2. `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g`

The definition `fmap` fails the first condition:

```
fmap id = map id . reverse = reverse != id
```

So that's not a functor at all!

And it even fails the second condition:

```
fmap (f . g) = map (f . g) . reverse
             = map f . map g . reverse
             = map f . fmap g
             = reverse . map f . reverse . fmap g
             = reverse . fmap f . fmap g
             != fmap f . fmap g
```

Which is quite clear if you think about it:

- `fmap (f . g)` reverses the list once and then maps its elements via `f . g`
- `fmap f . fmap g` reverse the list, maps via `g`, *then reverses the list again* and then maps via `f`!

Comment: Wow, brainfart! Thanks for clearing that up